# Word that means: making sure it does not happen again in the future

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Im looking for a word that means:

> making sure it does not happen again in the future

Context:

> We do not want to distract from this but are focused now on rectifying and _____ [making sure the mistake is not repeated by doing XandY]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... on rectifying, and on *precluding* any repetition.

I find it difficult to place an intransitive verb here so suggest transitive *preclude*.

> Preclude = to forestall, to head off
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preclude)